# Reading data from a json file using python

Tags: python, json

**I have been trying to read data from a json file using python 3.8 but I always receive this traceback error;**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Powerful Richie/Desktop/My Python Codes/roster.py", line 1, in <module>
    import json
  File "C:/Users/Powerful Richie/Desktop/My Python Codes\json.py", line 11, in <module>
    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(address)
  File "C:\Users\Powerful Richie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Powerful Richie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 509, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "C:\Users\Powerful Richie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "C:\Users\Powerful Richie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 354, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Users\Powerful Richie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'roster_data.json'
```

**Who can help me rectify this error please?**

Comment: Hey Richmond. It is more helpful if you post your original code so that we can see what the lines are referring to in your error code.

Comment: Can you also post the code that gives this error?

Comment: Please provide  the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are adding the full location of the file that you are trying to locate

```
import json

with open('path_to_file/roster_data.json') as f:
data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

it should not be just roster_data.json or check the right location of the file

Comment: Still not working please

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: Never mind, I've rectified the mistake. Thanks for the concern.